# AngularJS: Signup and Content Page in one index.html

Tags: html, css, angularjs, background, fullscreen

I am trying to put users who are not logged in on a login page, which should have a full screen background image and logged in users on the content page which should not have that full screen background image.

For now I have this:

```
<div ng-controller="mbMainCtrl as mainCtrl" class="container-fluid">
    <div ng-show="!$root.loggedIn" class="landing">
      <p>login</p>
    </div>

    <div ng-show="$root.loggedIn">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

My landing class looks like this:

```
.landing {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #DDD;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

I am using `background-color` here, but this shouldn't make a difference.

Now when `$root.loggedIn` is false, the whole screen should be grey (#DDD) with a little "test" written, right?

It looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHJwR.jpg (Sorry I cannot post images with my low reputation..)

Comment: why not mainCtrl.$root.loggedIn

Comment: I am using `$rootScope.loggedIn = 0;` in my controller, because I might need the loggedIn value somewhen later.

Comment: Try to look at the examples in app.js / routes of https://github.com/firebase/angularfire-seed

Answer (score 1):

The reason it's only one line high is because the CSS you have tells the div to take up 100% of it's **parent's** width and height. In this case, it's a div. Block level elements like a div fill the entire width of *their* parent, but don't expand unless there's content. This goes all the way up to the body element.

There's a couple ways around this, but I think for you it's easy to get around with position absolute:

```
.landing {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #DDD;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

This takes your div out of the flow of the document, and instead stretches it to the four corners of the window.